# How to terminate a button callback method in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this scenario:

```
button_a = tk.Button(self, text="<", command=self.button_a_clicked)
```

I assume that the `button_a_clicked` callback runs in a separate thread. Then I want another button `button_b` to first stop `button_a_clicked` and then perform its own task.

```
button_b = tk.Button(self, text="<", command=self.button_b_clicked)
```

So, how can I achieve that inside `button_b_clicked` callback. Is that achievable anyway?

I tried to make a boolean such that inside `button_b_clicked`, I set it to false and inside `button_a_clicked` whenever this boolean is false I exit the method. Something like this:

```
def button_a_clicked(self):
    self.flag = True
    while True: 
         if not self.Flag:
              return
         ... rest of code ...

def button_b_clicked(self):
    self.flag = False
    ... button b clickec logic (containing some loop) ...
```

However, I can see that, that condition in `button_a_clicked` is reached at some point of time after button_b_clicked already started and executed few iterations inside it. So is there a better way to force terminate `button_a_clicked` callback?

Edit: 
The exact scenario I am doing is in this method: 
https://github.com/b-safwat/video_labeling_tool_for_action_detection/blob/master/VideoPlayer.py#L111

Comment: Your button_a_clicked fucntion don't runs in a seperate thread. You shouldn't use loops in a GUI because in your case you can not press button_b  while your loop is running.

Comment: In my case, I am playing a long video so I have to use a loop and actually it does not freeze the GUI so I guess it is in a separate thread.

Comment: Tkinter is running in a single Thread so your function can't run in a seperate thread.

Comment: In my case I have this button click event: https://pastebin.com/z7hbCd7Q As you can see, there is a loop that takes a few minutes to run but the GUI is not freezing and I can use other functionalities as well. This is my first GUI and it is working fine so I do not have any other tricks, but how is it not freezing?
I have updated the question with the repository and a link to the exact function